# Arrays and for loops trouble

Tags: arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I am doing an array exercise and I almost finished it.I have trouble finishing the last part.I create two arrays that store coursework points and exam points and then using a third array I calculate the module result(it is determined by both exam and coursework points). I got this part working and assuming I have 5 modules the output is 5 numbers.However I want to calculate my stage mark so if I have 5 modules I get their marks,add them together and then divide them by 5.Here is my problem I am using for loop because that is the only way it will work(as far as I know) so given that I already have my module result I use this for loop to calculate the stage result:

```
for(int i = 0; i < module_result.length; i++)
{
    sum = sum + module_result[i];
    System.out.println(sum/5);
}
```

I saw in this site similar question and I used the code in the answers.I can use enhanced for loop as well.

So given that coursework `array={45,70,60,55,80}` and exam `array={83,72,45,25,89}` my module results are `64,71,60,87`. By using the above for loop I get anticipated outcome:

```
10
22
32
37
52
```

So I get my result. It is 52. But I don't want the rest of the numbers.
My question is how can I get just that number(52). I guess it is not possible by using for loop because it will inevitably  is going to loop 5 times not one. I thought about using while loop but I don't see how I will get much different outcome.

Comment: Couldn't you just move the print statement after the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I totally understand the question, but I think this is what you're going for:

```
for(int i = 0; i < module_result.length; i++)
{
    sum = sum + module_result[i];
}
System.out.println(sum/5);
```

All you have to do is simply move the println statement outside of the loop (if I understand the question correctly).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out the last number, just do a condition in the for loop that would print out at the index just before the length like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < module_result.length; i++) {
    if (i == module_result.length - 1) {
        // print results
    }
    else {
        // Do calculations
    }
}
```

OK here is my code.

```
public int[] computeResult(int []courseWork,int[] examMarks ){
        int[] module_result = new int[6];
        for(int i=0;i<module_result.length;i++){//CALCULATE EACH MODULE
            module_result[i]= ((courseWork[i] * cw[i]) + (examMarks[i] * (100 -  cw[i]))) / 100;//THIS LINE IS SIMPLY A CONDITION HOW TO CALCULATE A MODULE YOU DON'T NEED TO KNOW WHAT IS HAPPENING INSIDE
}
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < module_result.length; i++)//USE THIS FOR LOOP TO ADD THE MODULES TOGETHER.
        {
            sum = sum + module_result[i];

            // Add this extra line
            // This allows you to only print out the value when you reach the end
            if (i == module_result.length - 1) {
                System.out.println(sum/6);
            }
        }
        return module_result;
        }
```

However here is what happens-the first for loop calculate the module results.Say they are as follows in the output console:
64
71
60
31
87
33

Next the second for loop is adding them together-first is 64,next loop at 71 to 64 and you get 135,next add to 135 the next module result 60 and so on until I get the total sum of all 6 modules which is just in this example 346 and then divide it by 6 to get my stage result.So I need in my output console just 346/6.Nothing else no zeros no nothing.

What my current code does is this-the second loop star running,it already knows my module results(they have been calculated) and so it starts- the first one is 64,divide it by 6 I get outcome 10,then the loop add 71 to 64 get 135 and divide it by 6 and so on until it reaches the number 346 and divide it by 6.So I get this output:
10
22
32
37
52 
57

I don't need 10,22,32,37 and 52 they hold no meaning.I just need  57.What your solution will give me is this outcome:
0
0
0
0
0
57

It still gives unnecessary numbers.

Comment: I fixed your code to produce output that you wanted.